# Calling Google api's signout from another activity

Tags: android, google-plus-signin, google-signin

I have an activity called login. It has the Google API login buttons and functionality. When it is successfully logged, another activity will launch called LoggedIn.

When a button (id: Logout) is pressed, it has to go back to login, log the user out and show login button again . How can i do this ?

**LoggedIn Function**

```
package com.digidtheapp.digid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.*;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.*;
import com.google.android.gms.appdatasearch.GetRecentContextCall;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;

public class LoggedIn extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public  String name,pic,Email;
    public static String sn,sp,se;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String TAG = LoggedIn.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_logged_in);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        name =intent.getStringExtra("Name");
        Email = intent.getStringExtra("Email");
        pic = intent.getStringExtra("Profile");
        View header = ((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0);
        ((TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.user)).setText(name);

        View header2 = ((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0);
        ((TextView) header2.findViewById(R.id.emailField)).setText(Email);

        View imageChanger = ((NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view)).getHeaderView(0);

        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(pic)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into( (ImageView) imageChanger.findViewById(R.id.profilePic));











        Log.e(TAG,"name = "+name+"\n Email = "+Email+"\n Profile = "+pic);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, hello(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();


            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logged_in, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_History) {
            // Handle the camera action
        }

          else if (id == R.id.nav_Request) {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this ,Request.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else if(id == R.id.aboutUs)
        {
            finish();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this ,About.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if(id == R.id.Logout)
        {
            signOut();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }
    public String hello()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this ,Request.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return "act";
    }
    private void signOut() {
        new Login().signOutFromGplus();


    }

    }
```

**Login Function**

```
package com.digidtheapp.digid;



        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.LinearLayout;
        import android.widget.TextView;


        import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
        import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
        import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
        import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
        import  android.util.*;
        import android.view.Window;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = Login.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
    public  String name,email,pic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Login var = new Login();
        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        // Customizing G+ button
        btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    }


    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    public void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            Log.e(TAG, "display name: " + acct.getDisplayName());

             name = acct.getDisplayName();
             pic = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
             email = acct.getEmail();



            updateUI(true);
        } else {
            // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                signIn();
                break;


        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
        // be available.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog == null) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this ,LoggedIn.class);
            Log.e(TAG,name +"\t"+email+"\t"+pic);
            intent.putExtra("Name",name);
            intent.putExtra("Email",email);
            intent.putExtra("Profile",pic);
            startActivity(intent);


        } else {



        }
    }
    public void signOutFromGplus() {

     signOut();

    }
}
```

so my question is how to logout the user from the app from pressing Logout button on activity LoggeedI

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: How to logout the user from the app from pressing Logout button on activity LoggeedIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use the signOutFromGplus() method from LoggedIn, you can simply make it static, then call it with the following :

```
public static void signOutFromGplus(){...}
```

`Login.signOutFromGplus();`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this static method

```
public static void googleSignOut(Context context, Class destination) {
    // Configure Google Sign In
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.google_requestIdToken))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso);
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener((Activity) context, task -> {
                //user is signOut
                //sending user to destination class
                Intent i = new Intent(context, destination);
                context.startActivity(i);
            });
}
```

This is also logOut user from Google's sign in window and it will show

[image: This]

instead of signing in with the previous used email

hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making it static, before you try to navigate to another activity you can put your google signout code.

```
signOutFromGplus();
```

Now go to another activity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this ,LoggedIn.class);
 Log.e(TAG,name +"\t"+email+"\t"+pic);
 intent.putExtra("Name",name);
 intent.putExtra("Email",email);
 intent.putExtra("Profile",pic);
 startActivity(intent);
```